# Moving to GitLab from GitHub (as remotes in POSIX environment)

Tags: linux, git, github, find, gitlab

I'm migrating to GitLab. I need to edit all the .git/config files on my workstations which contain "github" and replace that word with "gitlab". I suspect that this can be done most easily with a single `find` command, rather than using a `git` call in each folder.

I think it would be something like:

```
find ./ -name ".git/config" -type f -exec sed -i 's/github/gitlab/gI' {} \;
```

Is this a safe/reasonable approach? What is the best way to do this?

Edit/Update: Comment: I actually do not want to do that for all github repos, since it is only the ones I control which are moving. I haven't revised my question, but the accepted answer includes a version to target only one github account. And my own answer below most literally accomplishes the goal of changing every file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to, you can use a single rule with [an `insteadOf` directive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).

```
git config --global url."https://gitlab.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "git@github.com:"
```

Then, any `git push/pull/clone` using a `github.com` URL would use `gitlab.com` instead.

The [OP CPBL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159005/cpbl) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711387/moving-to-gitlab-from-github-as-remotes-in-posix-environment/50712693?noredirect=1#comment88658813_50712693):

> So as not to change other GitHub packages I use, the following works for me:
>
> ```
> git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:cpbl".insteadOf "git@github.com:cpbl"
> git config --global url."git@gitlab.com/cpbl".insteadOf "git@github.com/cpbl"
> ```

Comment: Would this work, given the  `@gitlab.com` strings I found (see my answer below) that are not necessarily https?  Would it work to simply remove the "https://" in your answer? If so, would you consider updating it to be like that?  Or, to be safer, maybe using a directive for "gitlab.com:cpbl" and one for "gitlab.com/cpbl" ?

Comment: @CPBL I have updated the answer to take into account SSH GitHub URLs (tp be replaced with SSH GitLab URLs)

Comment: Thanks @VonC. So as not to change other github packages I use, the following works for me: `git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:cpbl".insteadOf "git@github.com:cpbl"` and 
`git config --global url."git@gitlab.com/cpbl".insteadOf "git@github.com/cpbl"`

Comment: @CPBL Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

To change only references to repositories in one account (safer) on github, use the following (let's say my username on github and gitlab is `cpbl`):

```
find ./ -wholename "*/.git/config" -type f -exec sed -i 's/github.com:cpbl/gitlab.com:cpbl/gI' {} \;

find ./ -wholename "*/.git/config" -type f -exec sed -i 's/github.com\/cpbl/gitlab.com\/cpbl/gI' {} \;
```

Obviously, you should replace "cpbl" with your desired github/gitlab username.
The two lines are needed because there may be both `url = git@gitlab.com:cpbl/` and 
`url = git@gitlab.com/cpbl/` references in your .git files.

Before proceeding with the above, to list what you're about to change, you can do:

```
find ./ -wholename "*/.git/config" -type f -exec grep github.com:cpbl {} \;

find ./ -wholename "*/.git/config" -type f -exec grep github.com\/cpbl {} \;
```

An advantage of this over @VonC's great idea is that you can make an exception this way (e.g. there is one repo I don't want to move today, so I can just change it back).

Comment: That should work indeed. +1. I'll keep my answer if that can help others.